# How to skin the UITableViewCell image used when selecting multiple rows?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

When you put the cell in edit mode and allow multiple cells to be selected at once, the UITableView shows a checkbox on the left of the cell, like below.

[image]

How do I change that image? Changing the cell.editingAccessoryView just adds another accessory to the right, instead of changing the left one.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for reading the question wrong at first.  Best I can find at the moment is the multiSelectCheckmarkColor property on the tableview.  This technically isn't what you are asking for... however, if simply changing the color is a sufficient solution for you then you might be interested this option.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it just shows how to display these cells, not really how to skin them.. I have this working, but would like to at least change the color, because I'm using the selection for another thing..

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks.. this worked: 
    [self.quickDialogTableView setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"multiselectCheckmarkColor"]; 
Isn't this against the rules though, calling undocumented methods? Wouldn't Apple catch this?

Comment: Yes, that's a very valid concern.  I believe I have literally read somewhere that they do check for calls to undocumented methods [I think on this site: http://appreview.tumblr.com/ ].  So, here is what I would do:  I would override / subclass the uitableview and then you should be able to access the actual multiselectCheckmarkColor property.  Technically, at that point you are accessing a property rather than calling an undocumented method... so, I would assume that they would be less strict in these scenarios and therefore less likely to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution I know is not using the default editing mode at all.
You can easily add a custom checkbox to your cell and animate the cell to show it when entering editation mode.

Comment: Right, I figured that would be an option, but I imagine there must be an easier way. I couldn't find anything in the docs, unfortunately, so maybe I'll have to do it all myself.